# git-daemon-sysvinit error. Unable to purge

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, dpkg, git, error-handling

So.. I recently tried to install `git-all` but it gave me a `git-daemon-run` error. I read that it is suggested to install `git-daemon-sysvinit` instead. However, now I am unable to install or purge anything. I get the following output when I try

`sudo apt-get install git-all git-daemon-sysvinit`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
git-all is already the newest version (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1).
git-daemon-sysvinit is already the newest version (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  fgetty
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up git-daemon-sysvinit (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Failed to start git-daemon.service: Unit git-daemon.service not found.
invoke-rc.d: initscript git-daemon, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-sysvinit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 git-daemon-sysvinit
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also get the same error if I try to uninstall or reinstall  git-daemon-sysvinit. So now I am basically stuck... I am running 16.04 LTS

Comment: No. I tried the methods explained in that question.

Comment: please try this `sudo apt remove --purge git-all`, then `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`, followed by `sudo apt install git-daemon-sysvinit git-all` __Please take note of the git install line, git-all should be last__.